# PHP turn object into array of array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables, after joining name and output the role with this

```
$encoded = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

I got this

```
{"student_id":"1","student_name":"john","score_id":"1","score_type":"E","score_name":"England"}
{"student_id":"1","student_name":"john","score_id":"2","score_type":"B","score_name":"Brazil"}
```

Now I'm struggling to turn them into the format I wanted, the client site have to have this

```
//json
[{
"student_id":"1",
"student_name":"john",
"scores": [{
        "score_id":"1",
        "score_type":"E",
        "score_name":"England"
    },{
        "score_id":"2",
        "score_type":"B",
        "score_name":"Brazil"
    }]
}]
```

The challenge is it has duplicated row with the same person.

Comment: sounds like you should adjust the query to remove the dupe

Comment: With json you have encode or decode. Can be object or assoc.

Comment: Do you know Doctrine2 ORM? You define models (objects) with sub attributes and map those to database tables. Doctrine fetches the rows and builds the objects... In your case probably a student model with score sub objects. In some cases you don't use ORM because of performance reasons... But it makes it much easier to handle complex data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Process the output using the Array `$encoded` and once it is built then you can print it with JSON.

In this solution the array will be indexed by `student_id` and the scores by `score_id`. In case of student it is a must, in case of scores it is recommended:

```
$encoded = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Student's details
  $encoded[$res['student_id']] = array(
      'student_id' => $res['student_id'],
      'student_name' => $res['student_name'],
  );
  // Student's score details
  $encoded[$res['student_id']]['scores'][$res['score_id']] = array(
      'score_id' => $res['score_id'],
      'score_type' => $res['score_type'],
      'score_name' => $res['score_name'],
  );
}
echo json_encode($encoded);
```

Note: this is general answer since I do not know exact structure of your data in $res.

Comment: @GlobinHughes I have updated the code to reflect you post updates.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code to get the json format as mentioned in your question

```
$students = [];
$sampleData    = [
          [

              "student_id"=>"1",
              "student_name"=>"john",
              "score_id"=>"1",
              "score_type"=>"E",
              "score_name"=>"England",
          ],
          [
              "student_id"=>"1",
              "student_name"=>"john",
              "score_id"=>"2",
              "score_type"=>"B",
              "score_name"=>"Brazil",
          ],
];
foreach ($sampleData as $res) {

    //if student not found by id then continue
    if (empty($res['student_id'])) {
        continue;
    }

    $student = [];
    //get the already exists student to add scores
    if(!empty($students[$res['student_id']])) {
       $student = $students[$res['student_id']];
    }


    //prepare the student array
    $student['student_id']             = $res['student_id'];
    $student['student_name']           = $res['student_name'];
    $student['scores'][]['score_id']   = $res['score_id'];
    $student['scores'][]['score_type'] = $res['score_type'];
    $student['scores'][]['score_name'] = $res['score_name'];

    $students[$res['student_id']] = $student;
}

echo json_encode(array_values($students));
```

hope this helps

You can find the working example [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/ijw)

Comment: can avoid this line? `$arr = $students[$res['contact_id']] ?? [];` I'm not using php 7 yet.

Comment: your answer doesn't work, I tried it, I gave me 2 array

Comment: Sorry unexpected error, please try again later or contact JDoodle support.